# Create a Python List with Multiple Elements per Iteration

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, iteration

```
def f1(x): return [(x+1)*2-1, (x+1)*2-1]
def f2(x): return [(x+1)*2, (x+1)*2]

[[f1(i), f2(i)] for i in np.arange(3)]
```

This is the code to generate a `list` of 3 list-pairs elements:

`[[[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[3, 3], [4, 4]], [[5, 5], [6, 6]]]`

However, I would like to obtain a `list` like below with **one line of `for` loop**.

`[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6]]`

This is how it works with multi-lines:

```
n = []
for i in np.arange(3):
    n += [f1(i), f2(i)]
```

It's like trying to compose 2 elements per time where I don't know how to achieve `+=` for one line of code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[x for i in np.arange(3) for x in [f1(i), f2(i)]]
```

Use a list comprehension with two `for` clauses.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is far one-line of code can go. But `[x for x in [f1(i), f2(i)] for i in np.arange(3)]` also works. That means the `for` order is optional?

Comment: The loop order matters. What you wrote does something entirely different, and probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I could do something like this:

```
[f1(i) for i in np.arange(3)] + [f2(i) for i in np.arange(3)]
```

But is there any better way?